# How to call someone in an empty room?

Tags: non-native-speaker

Imagine I have walked in to a room and nobody is there, but I'm pretty sure that someone is nearby.

How can I call someone in? Is there a general shout for that, or maybe it depends on what room it is (a small shop, a reception desk, my boss's office).

Answer (score 4):

I would say "Доброго дня, чи є хто-небудь?" ("Good day, is there anybody here?") in public. Or just "Чи є хто вдома?" ("Is someone at home?") at home.